# gulp fails on heroku: scss imports fail, bower_components missing?

Tags: node.js, heroku, gulp, bower

I am taking over a project from someone else. He devised a node app with bower and gulp.

They initially deployed onto AWS, now they want to switch to heroku. The former deployment process thus doesn't work anymore.

I advanced quite a bit, but I am hitting a brick now where I don't know how to continue.

I moved all gulp references from devDependencies to dependencies in package.json, and added a `postinstall` script.

So gulp actually now executes on heroku.
But I get errors:

```
remote:        [15:31:39] Starting 'extras-admin'...
remote:        [15:31:39] Finished 'default' after 848 ms
remote:        
remote:        events.js:141
remote:        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
remote:        ^
remote:        Error: client/styles/main.scss
remote:        Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ../bower_components/normalize-scss/normalize.scss
remote:        Parent style sheet: stdin
remote:        on line 1 of stdin
remote:        >> @import "../bower_components/normalize-scss/normalize.scss";
remote:        ^
remote:
```

Now I can execute this on my local machine and it works.

Why does the @import fail at heroku? Of course, `bower_compoents` is in my `.gitignore`file, so maybe gulp on heroku fails to create it or something?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have existing state on your local machine. What happens when you delete bower_components and node_modules? (`rm -rf bower_components node_modules`). Then npm install (`npm install --quiet --production`). Then start your app (`npm start`).

If it still works locally, then you should open a support ticket.

I suspect you'll see the same errors. After npm installs modules, you need to install bower components, then you need to run your gulp build. A clean way to set this up (if you don't want it to run on every postinstall) is to create a build script:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "bower install && gulp build",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
}
```

More info here:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-with-grunt